# Is it Possible to Burn a fuel (coal especially) without a flame or spark?

Tags: thermodynamics, combustion

Actually there was a topic of quality determination of coal where it was heated up to 750-950 degrees in order to burn its mixed volatile substances. I was wondering how coal itself wouldn't burn. Similarly for other fuels like petrol or gas; they catch fire only when a naked flame or spark is brought near it, not only upon heating. But there are another examples where spark or initial flame is not required, only temperature burns, like burning a paper with magnifying glass or an asteroid entering atmosphere. How it is not same in both the cases?

Comment: That's just not true.  Anything flammable will start burning when it gets hot enough. A "spark" or other flame is hot enough to initiate burning.

Comment: Why Coal doesnt burn in quality testing ?

Comment: When coal is heated to drive off the volatiles for making coal-gas, coke and analysis it is done in the absence of oxygen and air so no appreciable combustion takes place.  In the presence of air a substance will burn if the flash-point temperature is exceeded even if there is no hotter spark or exposed flame.

Answer (score 2):

It will burn instantly in [Chlorine Trifluoride](http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2008/02/26/sand_wont_save_you_this_time)

Comment: your answer reminds me of dimethyl cadmium..

Comment: http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2013/05/08/things_i_wont_work_with_dimethylcadmium

Answer (score 1):

To burn something usual means to oxidize the fuel. There is an other way to get energy without flame and by relative low temperatures between appox. 250°C and less than 40°C. This devices are called [fuel cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_cell) and the work with hydrogen and a lot of other materials.

Comment: Well, the fuel is always oxidizing; just rather slowly until you reach the flash point.